# Popen report error: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, popen

```
cmd = ['scons', '-c', 'SHARED=yes', 'STATIC=yes']
```

when I tried to execute subprocess.Popen(cmd), just got the error prompt as below:

```
scons -c SHARED=yes STATIC=yes

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 37, in <module>
    if Popen(cmd).wait():
  File "D:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I was completely confused about this, is there anyone who could help me figure out? I was just a rookie on Python, thanks for a bunch!

Comment: Do you have scons installed and in PATH?

Comment: looking into this as well, i'll update if I figure it out.